# Running Into Segmentation Fault When Attempting To Convert String To Double in C++

Tags: c++, string, stringstream

I'm working on a fairly straightforward priority scheduling program which takes a text file with lines in the format:

```
[N/S/n/s] number number
```

And I'm attempting to convert the numbers into a double format. I'm trying to do this with a stringstream (this is a class project which must run on a version of Linux without stod), using the example here as a reference: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-strings-numbers-cc/

The problem is, when I try and implement what I'd think should be a fairly simple few lines of code to do this, I'm met with "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)" which seems directly related to my attempt to actually send the stringstream to the double variable I've created. I've included my code so far (still obviously quite far from done) and have also indicated the last line I'm able to execute by outputting "made it to here." I'm very confused about this issue, and would appreciate any help available. Note that although I've posted my entire code for completion's sake, only a small part near the bottom is relevant to the question, which I've clearly indicated.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<sstream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <unistd.h>
#include<pthread.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fstream>
#include<ctype.h>
using namespace std;

struct Train{
        public:
        char trainDirection;
        double trainPriority;
        double trainTimeToLoad;
        double trainTimeToCross;
};

void *trainFunction (void* t){cout << "placeholder function for "<< t <<endl;}

vector<string> split(string str, char c = ' '){

        vector<string> result;
        int start = 0;
        int end = 3;
        int loadCounter = 1;
        int crossCounter = 1;

        result.push_back(str.substr(start, 1));
        start = 2;

        while (str.at(end) != ' '){
                end++;
                loadCounter++;
        }

        result.push_back(str.substr(start, loadCounter));

        start = end + 1;
        end = start +1;

        while(end < str.size()){
                end++;
                crossCounter++;
        }

        result.push_back(str.substr(start, crossCounter));

        for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
                cout << result[i] <<"|";
        }

        cout<<endl;
        return result;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
//READ THE FILE

        const char* file = argv[1];
        cout << file <<endl;
        ifstream fileInput (file);
        string line;
        char* tokenPointer;
        int threadCount = 0;
        int indexOfThread = 0;

        while(getline(fileInput, line)){
                threadCount++;
        }

        fileInput.clear();
        fileInput.seekg(0, ios::beg);

//CREATE THREADS

        pthread_t thread[threadCount];

        while(getline(fileInput, line)){

                vector<string> splitLine = split(line);

                //create thread

                struct Train *trainInstance;

                stringstream directionStringStream(splitLine[0]);
                char directionChar = 'x';
                directionStringStream >> directionChar;
                trainInstance->trainDirection = directionChar;

                if(splitLine[0] == "N" || splitLine[0] == "S"){
                        trainInstance->trainPriority = 1;
                }
                else{
                        trainInstance->trainPriority = 0;
                }

                stringstream loadingTimeStringStream(splitLine[1]);
                double doubleLT = 0;
                cout << "made it to here" <<endl;
                loadingTimeStringStream >> doubleLT;        //THIS IS THE PROBLEM LINE
                trainInstance->trainTimeToLoad = doubleLT;

                stringstream crossingTimeStringStream(splitLine[2]);
                double doubleCT = 0;
                crossingTimeStringStream >> doubleCT;
                trainInstance->trainTimeToCross = doubleCT;

                pthread_create(&thread[indexOfThread], NULL, trainFunction,(void *) trainInstance);

                indexOfThread++;
        }
}
```

Comment: You used `argv[1]` without checking the number of arguments. Are you sure you passed the required parameter?

Comment: Yes, I haven't implemented error checking yet but am sure that the input is correct.

Comment: Steer clear of that `void *` mumbo-jumbo if you can. It can be an unending source of bugs and almost never needed in C++. That said, `trainFunction` promises to return a `void*` and doesn't. The compiler is now allowed to generate all sorts of fanciful code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your code that lead to undefined behavior and that's the cause of your segmentation fault. Namely:

- You don't check the number of arguments before using them
- You do not return a value in `trainFunction`
- You do not create a valid object for `trainInstance` to point to

The first two are somewhat obvious to solve, so I'll talk about the last one. Memory management in C++ is nuanced and the proper solution depends on your use case. Because `Train` objects are small it would be optimal to have them allocated as local variables. The tricky part here is to ensure they are not destroyed prematurely.

Simply changing the declaration to `struct Train trainInstance;` won't work because this struct will be destroyed at the end of the current loop iteration while the thread will still be potentially alive and try to access the struct.

To ensure that the `Train` objects are destroyed after the threads are done we must declare them before the thread array and make sure to join the threads before they go out of scope.

```
Train trainInstances[threadCount];
pthread_t thread[threadCount];

while(...) {
    ...
    pthread_create(&thread[indexOfThread], nullptr, trainFunction,static_cast<void *>(&trainInstances[indexOfThread]));
}
// Join threads eventually

// Use trainInstances safely after all threads have joined

// trainInstances will be destroyed at the end of this scope
```

This is clean and works, but it isn't optimal because you might want the threads to outlive the trainInstances for some reason. Keeping them alive until the threads are destroyed is a waste of memory in that case. Depending on the number of objects it might not even be worth it to waste time trying to optimize the time of their destruction but you can do something like the following.

```
pthread_t thread[threadCount];
{
    Train trainInstances[threadCount];
    while(...) {
        ...
        pthread_create(&thread[indexOfThread], nullptr, trainFunction,static_cast<void *>(&trainInstances[indexOfThread]));
    }
    // Have threads use some signalling mechanism to signify they are done
    // and will never attempt to use their Train instance again

    // Use trainInstances

 }  // trainInstances destroyed

    // threads still alive
```

It is best to avoid pointers when dealing with threads that don't provide a C++ interface because it is a pain to deal with dynamic memory management when you can't simply pass smart pointers around by value. If you use a `new` statement, execution must always reach exactly one corresponding `delete` statement on the returned pointer. While this may sound trivial in some cases it is complicated because of potential exceptions and early return statements.

Finally, note the change of the `pthread_create` call to the following.

```
pthread_create(&thread[indexOfThread], nullptr, trainFunction,static_cast<void *>(&trainInstances[indexOfThread]));
```

There are two significant changes to the safety of this line.

Use of `nullptr` : `NULL` has an integral type and can silently be passed to non-pointer argument. Without named arguments, this is a problem because it is hard to spot the error without looking up the function signature and verifying the arguments one-by-one. `nullptr` is type-safe and will cause a compiler error whenever it is assigned to a non-pointer type without an explicit cast.

Use of `static_cast` : C-style casts are dangerous business. They will try a bunch of different casts and go with the first one that works, which might not be what you intended. Take a look at the following code.

```
// Has the generic interface required by pthreads
void* pthreadFunc(void*);

int main() {
    int i;
    pthreadFunc((void*)i);
}
```

Oops! It should have been `(void*)(&i)` to cast the address of `i` to `void*`. But the compiler won't throw an error because it can implicitly convert an integral value to a `void*` so it will simply cast the value of `i` to `void*` and pass that to the function with potentially disastrous effects. Using a `static_cast` will catch that error. `static_cast<void*>(i)` simply fails to compile, so we notice our mistake and change it to `static_cast<void*>(&i)`

Answer (score 1):

You dereferenced `trainInstance` via `->` operator without assigning valid buffer, so the system will try to write to weird place and cause segmentation fault.

You can allocate buffer like this:

```
struct Train *trainInstance = new struct Train;
```

`struct` is not needed here, but I used one because it is used in the original code.

Also don't forget to check the number of arguments before using `argv[1]`.

Comment: Wow, worked like magic and NEVER would have thought of this as the cause of the error! You just cleared up hours of headaches, thank you so much and I'll accept the answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I'm sure your intentions are good but this answer can do a lot of harm. You're obviously replying to someone who isn't proficient with pointers, so why are you not showing the corresponding `delete` statement? Even better, why not change it to a local variable?

Comment: @patatahooligan the object's address is given to a thread which persists after the loop exits, so changing to a local variable would not be appropriate. Good point about the `delete` however (using smart pointers would be better)

Comment: I posted an answer because it was too much to describe in a comment but it can be done with a local variable outside the loop.